# Where to check LDAP query from Cloudera Navigator?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, cloudera, cloudera-navigator

I configured our Cloudera Navigator service to authenticate via LDAP. I'm able to login in Navigator, however I instantly get an error:

> You are not authorized to view this page

When I log in with full administrator and try to search for LDAP groups to add, I get nothing returned, so I think there is something wrong with my configuration. Where should I be able to see how does the LDAP query look like?

I use identical settings for LDAP as I used when configuring Cloudera Manager, where everything works fine. The LDAP group I'm looking for has a "Navigator" admin role assigned in CM.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this tool to monitor which queries are performed on the AD :

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/downloads/adinsight